# Does Heroku with Bonsai support anything higher than 7.10 of elasticsearch?

Tags: heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

I am getting security warnings because client `7.13.0` has issues. However, I use Bonsai with Heroku which is server `7.10.2` and that is incompatible with the `7.15.0` client.

I tried the following

`heroku addons:create bonsai -a <app> --version=7.14.2`

But it is still showing 7.10.2

Can I get Heroku to support the newer version of elastic search server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonsai support here. The current list of our supported Elasticsearch versions is [here](https://docs.bonsai.io/article/139-which-versions-bonsai-supports). This list is the same whether you have a cluster with us directly or through Heroku. Trying to provision a version of Elasticsearch that's not on this list will get you the closest available version to what was requested.

To shade in some context about why we're still running 7.10.2, it's important to know that in January 2021, Elastic [announced](https://www.elastic.co/blog/licensing-change) that version 7.11 and on would be licensed under the Server Side Public License (SSPL) and not Apache 2.0.

This change has pretty severe implications for hosted Elasticsearch providers like Bonsai, and has limited our ability to release new versions. We're working on some long term solutions, but the process has been slower than we'd like.

In any case, Elasticsearch 7.10.2 is the latest Elasticsearch version we offer as of December 2021 (check the first link for updates). We also [support OpenSearch](https://bonsai.io/blog/welcome-to-opensearch), which is an Apache 2-licensed fork of Elasticsearch, maintained by AWS.

As always, please don't hesitate to reach out to us at support@bonsai.io with questions or issues.

Comment: How do we create the Heroku addon for a specific release instead of just defaulting to Elasticsearch? I want to use opensearch instead

Comment: If you use the Heroku command line to attach Bonsai to your app, you can use the `--engine` flag. So `--engine=opensearch` should do what you want. You can also use this flag in your app.json. See this link: https://docs.bonsai.io/hc/en-us/articles/13929190533268-Heroku

Answer (score 1):

[Not at the moment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#installing-the-add-on), at least via Bonsai:

> **Protip:** Bonsai supports a command line flag for specifying which version of Elasticsearch you want to use. Note that we only support specific versions of Elasticsearch, so you can’t provision an arbitrary one. We have a list of available versions documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/foundelasticsearch#supported-versions-and-plugins).

[That link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/foundelasticsearch#supported-versions-and-plugins) leads to a page that lists support for 5.6.16, 6.5.4, and 7.10.2 for multi-tenant classes and 1.7.5 to 7.10.2 for single-tenant.

Note that this page is on the `docs.bonsai.io` domain, so it is *Bonsai*-specific, not Heroku-specific.

The official Elasticsearch addon [appears to support newer versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/foundelasticsearch#supported-versions-and-plugins), but it costs a minimum of $67 USD per month:

> We support the two most recent major versions at all times

[Searchbox *might* do what you want](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/searchbox#installing-the-add-on), and it has a free tier:

> For specific version of Elasticsearch please use CLI command with version information as;
>
> ```
> heroku addons:add searchbox:starter --es_version=2
> ```
>
> - Available versions are 0,1,2,5,6 and 7

It isn't clear what minor versions are used.